# Ordering by status value 1 and order by name asc records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get records of users, i want to get 10 users and than who user have status=1 its display first and if two user's name start with same alphabet it will show order by name asc who user have status=1, User's status should have 0 or 1. **short order by  name only those user's who have status=1**

here is my query

```
 SELECT users_id, concat(users_fname, ' ', users_lname) as name,
 IFNULL(users.users_age, '') as users_age 
 FROM `users` ORDER BY status DESC, name ASC LIMIT 10
```

Thanks in advance, please help me to short it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope it will help you

```
ORDER BY status DESC, (CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),name ASC
```

here is whole query

```
SELECT users_id, concat(users_fname, ' ', users_lname) as name,
 IFNULL(users.users_age, '') as users_age 
 FROM `users` ORDER BY status DESC, (CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),name ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Ok let me check @mayur panchal

Comment: Nice solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RAND` in the `ORDER BY` clause has as a consequence that users will be ordered randomly irrespective of their `status`.

You have to place the selection of 10 random records in a subquery and then consume this set in an outer query that orders by `status` as desired:

```
SELECT users_id, name, users_age
FROM 
(
   SELECT users_id, concat(users_fname, ' ', users_lname) as name,
          IFNULL(users.users_age, '') as users_age 
   FROM `users` 
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
) AS t
ORDER BY status DESC, 
         CASE 
            WHEN status = 1 THEN name 
            ELSE 1
         END ASC
```

Comment: I need only sort those user name who have status 1, meaning if user1 and user2 and have status 1 and have name start with same alphabet like user2 and user1 so user1 is showing first because user1 alphabetically coming first and second is user2 and other who don't have their status 1 they should not be sorting by name.

Comment: this answer is nice but the problem with uppercase lower case letter

Comment: I tried to answer the question posted. You have to understand that SO is not a code writing service. You have to do some research to find out the way MySQL handles uppercase/lowercase differences: you can google `MySQL COLLATE`

Comment: i found all the rows are sorting with name asc please modify, i need sorting only those rows which have status=1